# Installing hapood 3.2 over docker- error of libc-bin

Tags: docker, hadoop, npm

While installing hadoop 3.2 with docker, I encounter the following error:

```
Setting up npm (3.5.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...
WARN engine npm@7.13.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine npm@7.13.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
/usr/local/lib
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "npm@latest" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/@npmcli/ci-detect-c7bf9552
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/@npmcli/ci-detect-c7bf9552' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/ci-detect'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/@npmcli/ci-detect-c7bf9552' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/ci-detect'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

The bash script, supplied with Hadoop 3.2 source file and contains the docker commands, is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash



set -e               # exit on error

cd "$(dirname "$0")" # connect to root

docker build -t hadoop-build dev-support/docker

if [ "$(uname -s)" = "Linux" ]; then
  USER_NAME=${SUDO_USER:=$USER}
  USER_ID=$(id -u "${USER_NAME}")
  GROUP_ID=$(id -g "${USER_NAME}")
  # man docker-run
  # When using SELinux, mounted directories may not be accessible
  # to the container. To work around this, with Docker prior to 1.7
  # one needs to run the "chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t" command on
  # the directories. With Docker 1.7 and later the z mount option
  # does this automatically.
  if command -v selinuxenabled >/dev/null && selinuxenabled; then
    DCKR_VER=$(docker -v|
    awk '$1 == "Docker" && $2 == "version" {split($3,ver,".");print ver[1]"."ver[2]}')
    DCKR_MAJ=${DCKR_VER%.*}
    DCKR_MIN=${DCKR_VER#*.}
    if [ "${DCKR_MAJ}" -eq 1 ] && [ "${DCKR_MIN}" -ge 7 ] ||
        [ "${DCKR_MAJ}" -gt 1 ]; then
      V_OPTS=:z
    else
      for d in "${PWD}" "${HOME}/.m2"; do
        ctx=$(stat --printf='%C' "$d"|cut -d':' -f3)
        if [ "$ctx" != svirt_sandbox_file_t ] && [ "$ctx" != container_file_t ]; then
          printf 'INFO: SELinux is enabled.\n'
          printf '\tMounted %s may not be accessible to the container.\n' "$d"
          printf 'INFO: If so, on the host, run the following command:\n'
          printf '\t# chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t %s\n' "$d"
        fi
      done
    fi
  fi
else # boot2docker uid and gid
  USER_NAME=$USER
  USER_ID=1000
  GROUP_ID=50
fi

docker build -t "hadoop-build-${USER_ID}" - <<UserSpecificDocker
FROM hadoop-build
RUN groupadd --non-unique -g ${GROUP_ID} ${USER_NAME}
RUN useradd -g ${GROUP_ID} -u ${USER_ID} -k /root -m ${USER_NAME}
RUN echo "${USER_NAME} ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" > "/etc/sudoers.d/hadoop-build-${USER_ID}"
ENV HOME /home/${USER_NAME}

UserSpecificDocker

#If this env varible is empty, docker will be started
# in non interactive mode
DOCKER_INTERACTIVE_RUN=${DOCKER_INTERACTIVE_RUN-"-i -t"}

# By mapping the .m2 directory you can do an mvn install from
# within the container and use the result on your normal
# system.  And this also is a significant speedup in subsequent
# builds because the dependencies are downloaded only once.
docker run --rm=true $DOCKER_INTERACTIVE_RUN \
  -v "${PWD}:/home/${USER_NAME}/hadoop${V_OPTS:-}" \
  -w "/home/${USER_NAME}/hadoop" \
  -v "${HOME}/.m2:/home/${USER_NAME}/.m2${V_OPTS:-}" \
  -u "${USER_ID}" \
  "hadoop-build-${USER_ID}" "$@"
```

and I used the following command to run the file:

```
sudo ./start-build-env.sh
```

Edit: tried to install hadoop with marven over two days, but I have problem installing the pre-existing packages, and don't know what do about it. Thus I tried the docker version, which consider to be easier, but it does not works...

Comment: Where is Docker coming to the picture? Is this command run inside a docker? Could you show the commands you were trying to execute?

Comment: I am no expert in docker, but I uploaded the installation docker source code, supplied by Hadoop source files. I don't really know how to begin with debugging the problem..

Comment: @ErangaHeshan do you need more information on code? or is it OK?

Comment: Could you share the link to this script file in Hadoop? The error you're getting is from `npm`, while I don't see any `npm` commands in that file

Comment: @ErangaHeshan you mean where I find  the above bash script?
I download the source of https://hadoop.apache.org/release/3.2.2.html. To build hadoop, I needed to run ./start-build-env.sh, which can be found in source.

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I also had the same isue while trying to build Hadoop from source. It will be more easier to use [already built hadoop image from docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker). Sorry, I couldn't help you.